# mollification of harmonic function is harmonic (Green's identity)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, greens-theorem

[image]

For the equality $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Delta_y \eta_\epsilon(x-y)u(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \eta_\epsilon(x-y)\Delta_yu(y)$, did we perform integral by parts twice? If so, do we need any information of u on boundary? Otherwise, the integral by parts formula does not work. We can not cancel the term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you apply the integration by parts formula twice (Green's identity). The boundary terms vanish because the mollifier $\eta_\epsilon$ is by definition compactly supported.

Comment: I have tried the computation, but I still have the boundary term which is related to u. U is not compact supported, I can not cancel out the term. I am wondering if you could show me how to apply the second integral by parts

Comment: @000000000 The boundary term that you are referring to contains also the outward normal derivative of $\eta_\epsilon$ which is also zero on the boundary.

Comment: Because this integral is defined on $R^n$. Is the integral over$\partial R^n$ well defined?

Comment: @000000000 No but the integral over $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equal to the integral over the support of $\eta_\epsilon$ because everything outside of the support vanishes. So in this case the integration over $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the same as the integration over the ball $B(x,\epsilon)$. You could even integrate over the ball $B(x,2 \epsilon)$. This makes it even more clear why all derivatives of $\eta_\epsilon$ vanish.